# I can't create a table in xampp because of error 105 cant create table .... errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: mysql, database, xampp, computer-science

my sql query is to create foreing key from student_reg

```
create database student_portal;
--student_reg
CREATE TABLE student_reg(
    `id` INT(40) NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
    `reg_no` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(40),
    `name`  VARCHAR(255),
    `password`  VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    `course` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    `school`  VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL
  );
--NO FOREIGN KEY PART
--semester_reg
CREATE TABLE semester_reg(
    `id` INT(40) NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
    `reg_no` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `year` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    `reg_date` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    `semester_no` INT(1) NOT NULL,
    `school` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `unique_no` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
    -- ,
     CONSTRAINT `fk_semregno` foreign key (`reg_no`) references student_reg(`reg_no`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_sememail` foreign key (`email`) references student_reg(`email`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_semschool` foreign key (`school`) references student_reg(`school`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE

       );
```

on running this is what i get in the second create i run into this error for some reason

ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `student_portal`.`unit_reg` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
MariaDB [student_portal]>

Comment: Please post  `create table student_portal.unit_reg` statement . The query in the question [work fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=9dd4e6a62a81f3756704f69de5d5e3c2)

Comment: @Ergest Basha DBFIDDLE will tick every correct statement but any errors lower in the script will be ignored.. the second create is not ticked. In dbfiddle use 1 row for each statement and you will get the error the user is seeing. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=866eade68268fb4ea78060a54e084a98

Comment: You need keys on student_reg(`reg_no`) and student_reg(`email`) and student_reg(`school`) see manual for more https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html Although you seem to be duplicating information..and that error is not from the published code

Comment: @P.Salmon I saw the missing indexes but I was confused because of the error. The error should be `ERROR 1822 (HY000): Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'fk_semregno' in the referenced table 'student_reg'`. Anyway with the suggestion you gave it will work fine

Comment: @ErgestBasha: you will get that error message in MySQL, see: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=aef4b7bb11ca781d57de805f201cd326)

Comment: @Luuk yeah I saw that , but the `OP` has posted different error related to `unit_reg` table which is not on the question query

Comment: Because you use `INT(40)` you should not expect that you can store id's with 40 numbers, see [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8612a169ab69f8da78ade8f272350018)